# Dictionary where values are dictionaries not updating

Tags: python

I want to create a dictionary where each value is a dictionary. Here's what I have:

```
start = 1
for i in range(3):
    updated_payload = payload
    updated_payload["params"]["dsoJsonData"]["ReadMap"]["Some"]["StartIndex"] = start
    x[i] = updated_payload
    start = start + 1
```

Where `payload` is also a dictionary with all the needed attributes. I am just changing the `StartIndex` attribute to whatever the loop is at that time. However, when I run this piece of code all my dictionaries' keys have the same exact values. `StartIndex` all equal to 3. Why are they all getting the same value and how can I fix it so that it gets its respective iteration number?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and provide a complete example.

Comment: In particular, notice what some of the answers/comments say about `deepcopy`.

Comment: @CrazyChucky Yeah, I used `deepcopy` and it worked

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're referencing those dicts rather than copying them. So all of your `x[i]`'s are pointing the same dict. You should be copying them as the following:

```
x[i] = updated_payload.copy()
```

Comment: For some reason, I'm still getting three's

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to make a copy of the payload dictionary. You are directly assigning the value of payload to updated_payload so it's passed by reference instead of being copied.

```
updated_payload = payload.copy()
```